# How to change handlebars extension for express?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am new to node.js and I'd like to use handlebars template engine but with a shorten extension `hbs`.

Here is the original code ([source](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032977.do)):

```
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
.create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

It worked fine with templates with `handlebars` extension, but I changed it to:

```
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
.create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

And change all the template extentions to `hbs`.
However, now I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/node/myproject/views/layouts/main.handlebars'
   at Error (native)
```

I also tried

```
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
.create({ defaultLayout: 'main' , extname : '.hbs'});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

as per answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22278015/727695),

but I results in:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "500" in views directory "/path/to/myproject/views"
   at EventEmitter.render (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
   at ServerResponse.render (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
   at /path/to/myproject/app.js:96:6
   at Layer.handle_error (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
   at trim_prefix (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
   at /path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at Layer.handle_error (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
   at trim_prefix (/path/to/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
```

I tried other things too but none worked so wondering how can I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

This did the trick:

```
exphbs = require('express3-handlebars'),
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: To add to this. The 'hbs' engine name is also important.

Comment: This package is deprecated, use `express-handlebars`.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express3-handlebars

Comment: This package is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [express-hbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-hbs) instead of `express3-handlebars`.

Simply, you can do:

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs');
/*
...
*/
app.engine('hbs', hbs.express4({
  partialsDir   : __dirname +'/views/partials',
  defaultLayout : __dirname +'/views/layouts/default',
  extname       : '.hbs',
  layoutsDir    : __dirname +'/views/layouts',
}));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Comment: So isn't it possible with `express3-handlebars`?

Comment: It probably is. But `express3-handlebars` was renamed to `express-handlebars` and you're probably using Express 4, which is the current version. So, it's unlikely to work with the old module. If you change it to `express-handlebars` it'll be just fine. I'd rather use `express-hbs` because of consistency and its out of the box features like _i18n_ or _beautify_.

Answer (score 0):

'express3-handlebars' package is **deprecated** now(2020). So you can try this out

```
const handlebarOptions = {
    viewEngine: {
      extName: '.hbs',
      partialsDir: 'views',//your path, views is a folder inside the source folder
      layoutsDir: 'views',
      defaultLayout: ''//set this one empty and provide your template below,
    },
    viewPath: 'views',
    extName: '.hbs',
  };


mailTransport.use('compile', hbs(handlebarOptions));

const mailOptions = {
        from: '"Spammy Corp." <ad.timely@gmail.com>',
        to: 'nipunkavishka@gmail.com',
        template: 'index',//this is the template of your hbs file
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just need to create a folder within the **views** folder and name it to **layouts**, and then move your *defaultLayout* = `main.hbs` to it .

If you've got :
`Error : The partial header could no be found .`
Go create another file within the **views** folder again and name it to **partials** and then put all your partials there __*Like the header file and so on ... .*